# Use style from external assembly, which is in another solution

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a solution:
**[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNutY.png)**
In this solution I have a style which I want to use in another project, the style is in resource dictionary format. **Note:** This solution contains WPF class library.

In **another** solution I have a project, the solution explorer looks like this:
**[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQWLI.png)**

Now, I want to reference the CustomWindow.xaml resource dictionary in my App.xaml, so I could use it in my MainWindow.xaml.

```
<ResourceDictionary>
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="???"/>
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
<ResourceDictionary>
```

How to do so?

**The solution was:**

```
<ResourceDictionary>
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/CustomWindow;component/Styles/CustomWindow.xaml"/>
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
<ResourceDictionary>
```

Now, whenever I add the Style to my window from that DLL like this:

```
Style="{DynamicResource CustomWindowStyle}"
```

It shows wiggly lines on the code, and whenever I put a cursor on it, it shows an error: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"
**Note:** It compiles, but the designer won't shot how it really looks like.

Comment: I think I've seen this before. To work around it, I added the resources to the control where it was going to be used, i.e. `<ResourceDictionary>.....</ResourceDictionary>` under `<UserControl.Resources>` (or `<Window.Resources>` in your case).

Comment: But doesn't app.xaml do the same thing?

Comment: Yes. I think it's a bug in the designer.

Comment: Ok, thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use *pack URI*: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069(v=vs.110).aspx. In your case, it should be something like

```
<ResourceDictionary>
   <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
       <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/<assembly name>;component/Styles/CustomWindow.xaml"/>
   <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

If you are going to share resources, you might want to move the resources to another assembly.

Comment: I tried this, but it says that it cannot find the path...
assembly name is the project name, correct?

Comment: By default it is, but you can change it through the Properties. Also, make sure there is no .dll in the assembly name (before `;component`). Is the CustomWindow.xaml a resources file or a view with resources in it?

Comment: It is a window.

Comment: For some reason, when I had opened my IDE with the class library it couldn't find the path... So it basically works.